# Need help in Sorting csv files in python

Tags: python, sorting, csv

I am very new to scripting. Currently I am working on a script to read data from different files and then merge, sort and extract specific data.

Now I got stuck at sorting csv files using 4th column of my data. below is the code I am using

*

```
ifile = open('one.csv', 'r')
reader = csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=',')
sortedlist = sorted(reader, key=operator.itemgetter(3))
with open("Newfile.csv", "wb") as f:
         fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
         for row in sortedlist:
             fileWriter.writerow(row)
```

The above code is working when I sort the csv with first column....."operator.itemgetter(0)".

But when I put (3) or anything other than 0.....it is giving error as follows

IndexError: list index out of range

My csv file looks like

```
IP_range,Mask,Ad1,Ad2,Ad3
10.0.140.0, 255.255.0.0, 199u, Seattle, Fourth Avenue
10.0.140.1, 255.255.0.0, 193u, Windsor, Popular Avenue
```

I couldn't understand the issue..I tried with different delimiters..but no luck

Comment: You've posted insufficient data to reproduce your error, it's likely one of your csv's is either malformed or not the same format as the rest you need to do more debugging

Comment: Are you sure the `csv`'s delimiter is `,` and more than one columns?

Comment: For the sample data, I assume there are new lines in csv data you have dumped. Now for the given data, sorting works fine. But incase the csv is not correct(eg only 2 columns instead of 5), the issue is reproducible.

Comment: Why am I getting messages from Barun Sharma when the OP is using account Rakesh? Are you using multiple accounts?

Comment: Thanks for the response.....after i deleted many rows and re run the script it is working fine......as you suggested something is wrong in the csv file.....actually it is a merged file from a txt file and a htm file...i tried to gather the info from both files and put them under same column names....My sorting issue is resolved now...looks like I should re work on merging the files.

Thank you EdChum and Barun Sharma

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the *wrong formated lines* using a `list comprehension`.

Meanwhile use a `with` statement when reading files.

```
import csv
import operator
with open('one.csv', 'r') as ifile:
    ireader = [i for i in csv.reader(ifile, delimiter=',') if len(i) >3]  #covert works here
    sortedlist = sorted(ireader, key=operator.itemgetter(3))
    with open("Newfile.csv", "wb") as f:
         fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
         for row in sortedlist:
             fileWriter.writerow(row)
```